# Сортировка по полю и связанному полю Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Объяснение задачи: есть чаты и сообщения. Нужна сортировка по созданию чата и по сообщениям в чате. то есть, если чат  создался раньше, чем отправлялись любые другие сообщения, то он первый идет.
У меня была сортировка через поле таблицы связи

```
Chat::query()
        ->orderBy(Message::select('created_at')->whereColumn('messages.chat_id', 'chats.id')->latest()->take(1), 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Теперь нужно, чтобы это поле записалось как колонка messages_at и сортировалась через или что-то подобное:

```
->orderByRaw('CASE
                WHEN created_at < messages_at THEN messages_at
                WHEN created_at > messages_at THEN created_at
            END DESC')
```

Как мне это сделать?
Через join он джоинит все записи Message, а мне нужны только чаты.
Возможно есть способ просто как-то записать это поле со значением, а я дальше в коллекциях отсортирую как надо?

Comment: вам бы  в чате  хранить ID последнего сообщения. будете джойнить по нему сообщения и сортировать как надо. Заодно сможете в список чатов сразу вытаскивать текст сообщения и т..п, если надо.

Comment: в противном случае в сообщениях нужен индекс по `chat_id, created` чтобы он был покрывающим для подзапроса сортировки `(select max(created) from msgs where chat_id = x.id)`

Comment: но лучше бы вам вообще привести структуру таблиц ваших

Comment: @teran как это в laravel запрос запихать?